# rush install giving the message " You are not permitted to execute this command ". I tried sudo but still error

Tags: imodeljs

I am trying to work with imodeljs. I tried the steps that they have given.

I cloned the repo installed using

`npm install -g @microsoft/rush.`

Then I try rush install command it fails. It gives a error message

> "You are not permitted to execute this command.
>   Contact the systems administrator for further assistance."

`user@user-Precision-M4800:~/Desktop/imodeljs/imodeljs$ sudo rush install
[sudo] password for user:`

> You are not permitted to execute this command.
>   Contact the systems administrator for further assistance.

`user@user-Precision-M4800:~/Desktop/imodeljs/imodeljs$ sudo rush -c install`

> Local configuration error occurred.
>   Contact the systems administrator for further assistance.

`user@user-Precision-M4800:~/Desktop/imodeljs/imodeljs$ rush install`

> You are not permitted to execute this command.
>   Contact the systems administrator for further assistance.

Commands that are not working:
Install dependencies: rush install
Clean: rush clean
Rebuild source: rush rebuild
Run tests:
All tests: rush test
Core tests: npm test -s
UI tests: npm run test:ui -s
Presentation tests: npm run test:presentation -s

I am expecting to get listed devDependency, which I will get it with rush install.

But I am getting error message :
You are not permitted to execute this command.
Contact the systems administrator for further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. It happens because ubuntu module [rush](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/rush.8.html) was installed on the laptop

After uninstalling it from the ubuntu it works.

```
sudo apt purge rush
```

And install

```
npm install -g @microsoft/rush
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing admin privileges. Is this a work laptop? If so, you might need to contact your IT department. 
If it's a personal machine, can you log in as the root user and try again?
Which OS are you running?

Comment: Yes this is a work laptop. I logged in as user and also sudo nothing worked. Ubuntu18 is the OS.

Comment: I recommend verifying with IT that you have required permissions within your company's domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm install -g @microsoft/rush` within Ubuntu 18.10, either on a machine or docker container, you may come across this issue. If you run `which rush` you will find out the rush being called is in the wrong location `/usr/sbin/rush`(Look at your `npm install ... rush` log and you will see that its right place to be is under `/usr/bin/rush`).

You might fix this by changing your path to find the right rush install or (in case you're running docker), just call rush by its full path like `/usr/bin/rush update`